# mounting without -o loop

Tags: linux-kernel, device, mount, linux-device-driver, ramdrive

I have written a dummy (ram disk) block device driver for linux kernel.
When the driver is loaded, I can see it as /dev/mybd.

I can successfully transfer data onto it using dd command, compare the copied data
successfully.

The problem is that when I create ext2/3 filesystem on it, I have to use -o loop
option with the mount command. Otherwise mount fails with following result:

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on mybd,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

What could be the problem? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your driver unit and request routines? I have a ramdisk driver but have not seen this error, maybe seeing the code will help.

Comment: aah.. just crashed my linux system.. did a dd on wrong device!
Need to start over again from installing linux...
I will get back here if I can reproduce the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at:
http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/

You can run a Linux within a Linux system. That would allow you to quickly build and 'deploy' a new version of plugin. And all the changes you would do (eg. `dd`) would be done within the guest OS, so it wouldn't break your native OS. As I remember there was even a possibility to have a `delta` of your file system changes in a separate file, so you could easily restore the initial state of your guest file system.

Comment: Any luck reproducing this error? Interested to see what the issue is...

Comment: I'm also curious to see the source code to the driver.

Comment: Jumpinjoe, please post your source... we're all curious to see what's going on. I have seen similar/same errors but only on VRAM

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, if it works with `-o loop` and doesn't work without, then I have bad news for you: your "device" is actually just a plain file in /dev.  What does `ls -l /dev/mybd` show?  If its filesize is non-zero, it's a regular file, and has nothing to do with your driver.

Use `mknod` to create the device file yourself if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're starting over again. As a quick note about your previous attempt, did you make sure your device appeared in /dev as a *block* device and not a *character* one?

Answer (score 0):

Create a filesytem on the device before mounting it:

```
mkfs -t ext2 /dev/mybd
```

or

```
mke2fs /dev/mybd
```

Comment: Try checking dmesg or /var/log/messages...sometimes the kernel writes diagnostic info there.

Comment: aah.. just crashed my linux system.. did a dd on wrong device!
Need to start over again from installing linux...
I will get back here if I can reproduce the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The loop device is used to mount block special files on the linux filesystem emulating them as block devices. Hence, the mount throws error.